# How is configure to LinPhone Video Call Method in Swift 3 Language?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am configure to linPhone Video Call using Swift 3 language but i don't have any idea how to configure to linPhone Video Call method. In my app Audio call Configure successfully.

please, Give me any idea how to configure to Video call  in linphone method swift language.

Answer (score 3):

first of all you need to have compiled linphone with video codec you want to support.

Enable video disp

```
linphone_core_enable_video_display([LinphoneManager getLc], YES);
```

And set any view as video view for linphone. I have simple extension on UIView to call only enable on any view.

Linphone documentation http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__IOS.html

```
extension UIView {

    func enableLinphoneVideo() -> Bool {
        return LinphoneManager.instance().setLinphoneDisplay(self)
    }

    func disableLinphoneVideo() -> Bool {
        return LinphoneManager.instance().setLinphoneDisplay(nil)
    }
}
```

Or you can try to setup video policy as follow:

```
LinphoneVideoPolicy policy;
policy.automatically_accept = YES;
policy.automatically_initiate = YES;
linphone_core_set_video_policy([LinphoneManager getLc], &policy);
```

If video still doesn't work plese post your logs from linphone library.

Comment: Hiii, thanks for given solution.but I had done. it is working good

Comment: yes, when I upload the question after 24 hour, I am Solved this issues

Comment: You can mark it as correct one, for others which can open this question.